# Python WMI или winreg, получаем серийный номер USB устройства

Tags: python, windows, wmi

И снова здравствуйте, у меня опять странный вопрос, на который я никак не могу ответить.
Начну сначала.

Задача: Локальный сбор данных о количестве напечатанных страниц с принтеров, с последующей отправкой в MSSQL и дальнейший свод в отчет с сопоставлением информации по серийным номерам, на случай переноса принтера.

Описание проблемы, с самого начала: 
Все было хорошо, пока я не пришел к выводу, что нужно вытаскивать серийные номера из WMI. На Windows 10 в целом возможно сопоставить имя очереди печати  с именем принтера и преодолев небольшой путь назад, по списку полученных от Win32_USBControllerDevice устройств получить желаемое, за редкими исключениями (зависит от принтера).

Но на Windows 7 нет такого понятия, как очередь печати, точнее есть, но оно не отражается в Диспетчере устройств так, как это делается в Windows 10.

Вообще, можно было бы сформулировать вопрос так:

Как получить по имени принтера информацию о его USB порте. То есть, есть имя принтера, которое можно увидеть в "панели управления-устройства и принтеры" и есть USB-интерфейс этого принтера, как их сопоставить и сейчас я не о имени порта, вроде USB003, а о строке, вроде этой:

```
DeviceID = "USB\\VID_0A5F&PID_0027\\СЕРИЙНЫЙ НОМЕР ТУТ";
```

Какие данные я получаю:
1. Данные о постановке задачи на печать:

```
{'JobId': 3, 'pPrinterName': 'PRINTER_NAME', 'pMachineName': '\\\\localhost', 'pUserName': 'aaseev', 'pDocument': 'Microsoft Word - Документ.rtf', 'pDatatype': 'RAW', 'pStatus': None, 'Status': 9, 'Priority': 1, 'Position': 1, 'TotalPages': 1, 'PagesPrinted': 0, 'Submitted': pywintypes.datetime(2020, 4, 14, 3, 20, 42, 147000, tzinfo=TimeZoneInfo('GMT Standard Time', True))}
```

2. Информация о принтере из Win32_Printer:

{

```
    Attributes = 2625;
    AveragePagesPerMinute = 0;
    Capabilities = {4, 2};
    CapabilityDescriptions = {"Copies", "Color"};
    Caption = "PRINTER_NAME_1";
    CreationClassName = "Win32_Printer";
    Default = FALSE;
    DefaultPriority = 0;
    DetectedErrorState = 0;
    DeviceID = "PRINTER_NAME_1";
    Direct = FALSE;
    DoCompleteFirst = TRUE;
    DriverName = "PRINTER_NAME";
    EnableBIDI = TRUE;
    EnableDevQueryPrint = FALSE;
    ExtendedDetectedErrorState = 0;
    ExtendedPrinterStatus = 2;
    Hidden = FALSE;
    HorizontalResolution = 203;
    JobCountSinceLastReset = 0;
    KeepPrintedJobs = FALSE;
    Local = TRUE;
    Name = "PRINTER_NAME_1";
    Network = FALSE;
    PaperSizesSupported = {1};
    PortName = "USB003";
    PrinterPaperNames = {"User defined"};
    PrinterState = 0;
    PrinterStatus = 3;
    PrintJobDataType = "RAW";
    PrintProcessor = "winprint";
    Priority = 1;
    Published = FALSE;
    Queued = TRUE;
    RawOnly = FALSE;
    Shared = FALSE;
    ShareName = "PRINTER_NAME";
    SpoolEnabled = TRUE;
    Status = "Unknown";
    SystemCreationClassName = "Win32_ComputerSystem";
    SystemName = "localhost";
    VerticalResolution = 203;
    WorkOffline = FALSE;
```

};

3. Информация о принтере из Win32_USBControllerDevice:

DEPENDENT
instance of Win32_PnPEntity
{

```
Caption = "Поддержка USB принтера";
ClassGuid = "{36fc9e60-c465-11cf-8056-444553540000}";
CompatibleID = {"USB\\Class_07&SubClass_01&Prot_02", "USB\\Class_07&SubClass_01", "USB\\Class_07"};
ConfigManagerErrorCode = 0;
ConfigManagerUserConfig = FALSE;
CreationClassName = "Win32_PnPEntity";
Description = "Поддержка USB принтера";
DeviceID = "USB\\VID_0A5F&PID_0027\\**СЕРИЙНЫЙ НОМЕР ВОТ ТУТ**";
HardwareID = {"USB\\VID_0A5F&PID_0027&REV_0001", "USB\\VID_0A5F&PID_0027"};
Manufacturer = "Microsoft";
Name = "Поддержка USB принтера";
PNPClass = "USB";
PNPDeviceID = "USB\\VID_0A5F&PID_0027\\**СЕРИЙНЫЙ НОМЕР ВОТ ТУТ**";
Present = TRUE;
Service = "usbprint";
Status = "OK";
SystemCreationClassName = "Win32_ComputerSystem";
SystemName = "LOCALHOST";
```

};

DEPENDENT
instance of Win32_PnPEntity
{

```
Caption = "PRINTER_NAME";
ClassGuid = "{4d36e979-e325-11ce-bfc1-08002be10318}";
CompatibleID = {"CID_MS_GENERICPRINT"};
ConfigManagerErrorCode = 0;
ConfigManagerUserConfig = FALSE;
CreationClassName = "Win32_PnPEntity";
Description = "PRINTER_NAME";
DeviceID = "USBPRINT\\...\\6&840F8D5&0&USB003";
HardwareID = {"USBPRINT\\...", "..."};
Manufacturer = "ZDesigner";
Name = "PRINTER_NAME";
PNPClass = "Printer";
PNPDeviceID = "USBPRINT\\...\\6&840F8D5&0&USB003";
Present = TRUE;
Status = "OK";
SystemCreationClassName = "Win32_ComputerSystem";
SystemName = "LOCALHOST";
```

};

DEPENDENT
instance of Win32_PnPEntity
{

```
Caption = "PRINTER_NAME_1";
ClassGuid = "{1ed2bbf9-11f0-4084-b21f-ad83a8e6dcdc}";
CompatibleID = {"GenPrintQueue", "SWD\\GenericRaw", "SWD\\Generic"};
ConfigManagerErrorCode = 0;
ConfigManagerUserConfig = FALSE;
CreationClassName = "Win32_PnPEntity";
Description = "Локальная очередь печати";
DeviceID = "SWD\\PRINTENUM\\{4A2629B1-899A-4722-9728-82576A160020}";
HardwareID = {"PRINTENUM\\LocalPrintQueue"};
Manufacturer = "...";
Name = "PRINTER_NAME_1";
PNPClass = "PrintQueue";
PNPDeviceID = "SWD\\PRINTENUM\\{4A2629B1-899A-4722-9728-82576A160020}";
Present = TRUE;
Status = "OK";
SystemCreationClassName = "Win32_ComputerSystem";
SystemName = "LOCALHOST";
```

};

Если вы дочитали до этого места, то вам явно не все равно и возможно даже интересно, а может вы и вовсе знаете, как это сделать и я помогу вам совсем немножко этим:

Пожалуйста, не говорите про SNMP и всевозможные сервисы по сбору информации, SNMP вообще волшебная вещь, но не везде это реализуемо.

Пожалуйста, не говорите, что я дурачок (я и так знаю) и что Python не для того сделан, чтобы Windows-сервисы писать и информацию от WMI получать. Я люблю Python и мне очень хочется сделать это именно на нем, впрочем как сделать это на чем-нибудь другом я не знаю.

Comment: А где вопрос о проблеме, в чем "затык"?

Comment: Если очень кратко, то вопрос следующий: "как имея имя принтера вроде: "HP_600 M602 UPD PCL 5", получить его серийный номер, который выглядит так: "CNCVF5FXXX"?". Я почти пришел к решению (во всяком случае на 3 разных системах мне удалось получить желаемое), но не средствами WMI, а средствами реестра. Как только закончу, в зависимости от результатов, либо оставлю решение здесь, либо удалю вопрос, если смогу.
А проблем в том, что я не нашел способа средствами WMI сопоставить имя принтера и его серийник, который хранится в экземпляре USB класса, это такой ад, я прям не могу.

Answer (score 0):

Я не смог сделать требуемое средствами WMI, но смог с помощью реестра. Решение рабочее, но сырое, поэтому гарантировать 100% работоспособность я не могу. Если вам известен другой, метод, я с удовольствием его рассмотрю.

```
import winreg 

def getPrinterSerialFromReg(printerName):
    def findInUSBEnum(usbKey,instanceId):
        try:
            for i in range(9999):
                vidpidName = winreg.EnumKey(usbKey,i)
                vidpidKey = winreg.OpenKey(usbKey,vidpidName)
                try:
                    for vp in range(10):
                        SNName = winreg.EnumKey(vidpidKey,vp)
                        SN = winreg.OpenKey(vidpidKey,SNName)
                        try:
                            if str(winreg.QueryValueEx(SN,'ParentIdPrefix')[0]).lower() in str(instanceId).lower():
                                return SNName
                        except:
                            continue
                except:
                    continue
        except:
            return 'SN not found'

    try:
        mainKey = winreg.OpenKey(winreg.HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE,r'SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Print\Printers\\'+printerName+r'\\PnPData')
    except:
        return 'printer name not found'

    try:
        instanceId = (winreg.QueryValueEx(mainKey,'DeviceInstanceId')[0]).split('\\')[-1]
        usbKey = winreg.OpenKey(winreg.HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE,r'SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Enum\USB')
    except:
        return 'get key error'

    if 'dot4'.lower() in str((winreg.QueryValueEx(mainKey,'DeviceInstanceId')[0])).lower():
        dot4Key = winreg.OpenKey(winreg.HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE,r'SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Enum\DOT4')
        dot4fok = 0
        try:
            for i in range(9999):
                if dot4fok == 1:
                    break
                vidpidName = winreg.EnumKey(dot4Key,i)
                vidpidKey = winreg.OpenKey(dot4Key,vidpidName)
                try:
                    for vp in range(10):
                        SNName = winreg.EnumKey(vidpidKey,vp)
                        SN = winreg.OpenKey(vidpidKey,SNName)
                        try:
                            if str(winreg.QueryValueEx(SN,'ParentIdPrefix')[0]).lower() in  str(instanceId).lower():
                                instanceId = SNName
                                dot4fok = 1
                                break
                        except:
                            continue
                except:
                    continue
        except:
            return 'dot4 parent not found'

    SN = findInUSBEnum(usbKey,instanceId)
    while '&' in SN:
        instanceId = SN
        SN = findInUSBEnum(usbKey,instanceId)
    return SN

print (getPrinterSerialFromReg('PRINTER NAME'))
```

Answer (score 0):

.py

```
import winreg 
 
printerName = 'hp LaserJet 1010 HB'
mainKey = winreg.OpenKey(winreg.HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE,r'SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows     NT\CurrentVersion\Print\Printers\\'+printerName+r'\\PnPData')
instanceId = (winreg.QueryValueEx(mainKey,'DeviceInstanceId')[0]).split('\\')[-1] # 7&29A2BFB9&1&1
usbKey = winreg.OpenKey(winreg.HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE,r'SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Enum\USB')
dot4Key = winreg.OpenKey(winreg.HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE,r'SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Enum\DOT4')
vidpidName = winreg.EnumKey(dot4Key,0) #VID_03F0&PID_0C17&REV_0100&PRINT
vidpidKey = winreg.OpenKey(dot4Key,vidpidName)
SNName = winreg.EnumKey(vidpidKey,0) #6&1c93366b&2&0
SN = winreg.OpenKey(vidpidKey,SNName)
instanceId = SNName #6&1c93366b&2&0
vidpidName = winreg.EnumKey(usbKey,4) #VID_03F0&PID_0C17
vidpidKey = winreg.OpenKey(usbKey,vidpidName)
SNName = winreg.EnumKey(vidpidKey,0) #00CNFF157864
SN = winreg.OpenKey(vidpidKey,SNName)
SN = SNName #00CNFF157864
```

.vbs

```
Option Explicit
Dim oWMISrv, collDvcs, collUSBDvcs, iUSBDvc , iDvc, sDvcID, sPID, sVID, sSN

Function ReplaceX(ByVal sValue, ByVal sPattern, ByVal sNValue)
    Dim oReg : Set oReg = New RegExp
    oReg.Pattern = sPattern
    ReplaceX = oReg.Replace(sValue, sNValue)
    Set oReg = Nothing
End Function

Set oWMISrv = GetObject("winmgmts:\\.\root\cimv2")
Set collDvcs = oWMISrv.ExecQuery("Select * From Win32_USBControllerDevice")

For Each iDvc In collDvcs
     If InStr(iDvc.Dependent, "VID_") Then 
        sDvcID = ReplaceX(iDvc.Dependent, ".*""(.*)""", "$1")
        sPID = ReplaceX(sDvcID, ".*PID_([^\\]*).*", "$1")
        sVID = ReplaceX(sDvcID, ".*VID_([^&]*).*", "$1")
        sSN =  ReplaceX(sDvcID, ".*\\(.*)", "$1")
        Set collUSBDvcs = oWMISrv.ExecQuery _
            ("Select * From Win32_PnPEntity Where DeviceID = '" & sDvcID & "'")
            For Each iUSBDvc in collUSBDvcs
                If    ReplaceX(sSN, ".*(&).*", "$1") =  sSN then
                      Wscript.Echo _
                      "Name : " & iUSBDvc.Description & vbCrLf & _
                      "VID : "& sVID & vbCrLf & _
                      "PID : "& sPID & vbCrLf & _
                      "SN  : " & sSN & vbCrLf 
               End If
            Next
      Set collUSBDvcs = Nothing
      End If
Next

Set collDvcs = Nothing
Set oWMISrv = Nothing
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на stack overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]